# How to use a zoom effect and make a component visible at the same time in Actionscript / Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, zooming, show, effect

I want to introduce a canvas component by zooming from a height & width of 0.0 to 1.0.  I want the component to be invisible until the zoom begins and then for it to be visible when it begins zooming.

However, if I bind the zoom effect to a showEffect trigger on the component and then make the component visible, it will first show the component at its regular size for a split second before it begins the zoom effect.  If I combine the zoom effect and setting the component visible together in a parallel, it will also flash the component at its regular size for a split second before the zoom.  If I make the component visible when the zoom effect starts through its effectStart event, it still does it.  Does anyone know how to make it visible only when the zoom effect begins so that it doesn't flash the component at its regular size for a split second before the zoom effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an easy solution: Put the zoom effect and set property action, which sets the component to visible, in a Parallel together but add a nominal start delay of 50 ms to the set property action.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be easier to provide suggestions if you were giving us code.

That said, the reason the component "Flashes" at full size before the effect starts probably relates to the positioning and sizing of the component before the effect starts.  So, before you start the effect just set the height and width of the component to the zoomHeightFrom and zoomWidthFrom of the effect.

These things can be tricky to debug, though.  Especially without code.

Comment: But then the zoomHeightTo and zoomWidthTo would be the same as well.  I will try and get some code up soon